# get_intermediate_image_sizes() returning different values depending on is_admin()

Tags: thumbnails, images

I have checked the code of the "Simple Image Sizes" plugin and found out how "they" read the available thumbnail/image sizes.

However when I use the `get_intermediate_image_sizes()` function in a plugin with  an `if( is_admin() )` clause surrounding it, it only returns the 3 standard WP sizes (thumbnail, medium, large).

I have 4 custom images sizes registered with `add_image_size()`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are all image sizes returned when you call `get_intermediate_image_sizes` in the frontend (without `is_admin`)?

Comment: Hi, no, that was exactly the case. I couldn't get it to work at all in the front end. Found out that I had to use a "later hook" because WP wasn't ready with reading the additional sizes yet.

Comment: Ah, so you've solved it? In that case, please add an answer to your own question explaining your solution and accept it. That way, it can be useful to other people as well :-)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I read the image sizes inside the "init" hook at which point the additional sizes are not loaded yet by Wordpress. I used a "later" hook now and it works.